# Show columns that are not null php sql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to figure out a way to show only columns that have a value. I have a drop down menu, that I make it a variable ($val) so it shows only the row where $val is not null. However, from that row, I want it to show the rest of the columns that are not null. Any small help is really appreciated.

```
 $sql = "SELECT Name, $val
    FROM GP
    WHERE $val IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY $val DESC";

mysql_select_db('dbname');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{

    echo "Name: {$row[0]}  <br> ".
        $val, ": {$row[1]} <br> ".

        "--------------------------------<br>";
}
```

Example I have

test1  NULL  13  NULL 14

I want to show test1 with the two rows with values.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: That's what the query should do. Please provide a var_dump($val) at the beginning of this snippet. What is the result (or error) you get?

Comment: It's not easy to understand the second sentence of the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@user3349025 I suppose this answer your question. You can change the second paramater in `mysql_fetch_array` to get the column name if you want to display it.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM GP
    WHERE $val IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY $val DESC";

 mysql_select_db('dbname');
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   foreach($row as $column => $value) {
       if(!empty($value)) {
           echo "$column: {$value}  <br> ";
       }
   }

    echo "--------------------------------<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You could have written this in comment.

Comment: I gonna edit the answer. Sorry about that but I cant do a comment in others questions or answers.

Comment: I have a table 

Name       Number1    Number2   Number3

Name1      5                   NULL         6
Name2      NULL             7                98

I want to show that table in PHP, Avoiding Number two in name1 since the value is NULL. 

Makes sense?

If not, I can get a screenshot better. Since difficult to explain here without proper spacing explaining the table.

Comment: @user3349025 Please edit your question above and use the code style (indent by 4 spaces) to make it more readable

Comment: I cant understand what you put here. Could you separate columns from data. Exactly, @clemens321.

Comment: http://i63.tinypic.com/2qtk7ef.jpg

Taking the example of Age Old Bead  - TH : 24  (avoiding to show the one that are null and having a blank space)

Comment: But I want help him and I will answer it.

Comment: RajdeepPaul, Rami you both didnt help anyone. Should you try to answer it, instead of repeating one another.

Comment: I get error missing ; at
   foreach($i=1; $i < count($row); $i++) {

Want me to post the whole code? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It's correct now. If it solved your problem, pls mark as the answer.

Comment: I still get them all, the one with blank, and the one with values. 

And all named "Name: "

How can I make it appear the Column name instead of Name: 

Thanks, for your time.

Comment: Did you read what I said about the column name above in the anwser? I edit it again.

Comment: As you may have noticed, I'm not that experienced. And have tried changing the parameter with same result. And the main problem is still there too, still not excluding the null one. 

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I see you made a change, lemme retry. Thanks.

Comment: You're the best, it worked! 
Last thing is how to show the column name instead of Name:? 

What exactly you mean when you say changing parameter?

Comment: I  edited it. Try it again. It should not return any empty result. I'll edit again to return the right column name.

Comment: I changed MYSQLNUM to MYSQL_ASSOC you can see the diff here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in Line    foreach($row as => $column => $value) {

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have no idea how much that helped. I need help by making the selected option ($val) the first row to show. Should I need to create a new question?

Comment: Yes. You should do a new one. Dont take this wrong, but you should show more effort in your question. You should do more than copy+paste.